# Object set to nil after if condition

Tags: list, core-data, swiftui

This works - all student.name entries are correctly displayed

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

let students = loadData()

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

            NavigationView {
                List(students) { student in
                    HStack {
                        Text(student.name ?? "No data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this - not. After correctly skipping "if", "students" become nil.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UserEntity name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000343f840' V

XCode Version 13.0 (13A233)

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

let students: [UserEntity] = loadData()

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {


        if students.isEmpty{
            NoDataView()
        }
        else{
            NavigationView {
                List(students) { student in
                    HStack {
                        Text(student.name ?? "dsada")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe off-topic but you have declared `students` outside of your struct making it some sort of global variable and that is a poor design decision. Why are you not using a `@FetchRequest` solution here?

Comment: It is not the `if` statement that is getting you, it is the way you instantiated `students`. In the first, you declare it as `let students = loadData()`, in the second, you declare it as `let students: [UserEntity] = loadData()`. We have no idea of what a `loadData()` is, nor do we care. @JoakimDanielson is absolutely correct. This is not how you use `CoreData`. I agree it looks like you have created some global source of truth, but that is what your database is. And you access it in all the views you need to by `@FetchRequest`. With that, `CoreData` implements the rest.